# C++ crypto library use in Apple Swift

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, cryptography

after reading the meta I believe this is the best place for this question ( I wasn't sure if it belongs here as it is not about specific code). 
The question is: Is Apple's Swift programming language suitable for a cryptography intensive iOs/MAC OS X project?
Why this question concerns me is that swift is inter compatible with objective-C but I'm not sure how compatible is it with C++ crypto libraries? I am thinking about using a C++ library for the crypto side of the app (eg: Crypto++). Has anyone integrated such a library in a swift app? Is it feasible or would the best option be to do a Objective-C++ wrapper for the library and use that from Objective-C ?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to use a C library since Objective-C is a superset of C. That said, they provide [their own set of crypto libraries and services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH1-SW1) and you should probably look into those first.

Comment: The problem is I don't want the default crypto that apple provides. In fact 99% of what is needed is only in C++ crypto libraries. (Things like Serpent and Blake2, NTRU). Most C libraries don't have thous algorithms either.

Comment: You can write wrapper in C for that, then wrapper in Swift to that C wrapper. This should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift currently has no way to directly interact with C++. You'd have to wrap everything in ObjC interfaces with ObjC++ implementations. If you're going to work with Crypto++ (which is fine if you need algorithms not available in CommonCrypto), then personally I would write all the low-level stuff in pure C++, and just do the UI work in Swift, using a small ObjC++ interface layer to read the results.

I always recommend minimizing your ObjC++ footprint, so even if you wrote this in ObjC rather than Swift, my recommendation would be the same. Write the UI code in pure ObjC and the engine in C++ and put a thin ObjC++ layer between them.

(Note that I have a strong bias against ObjC++ because I've been burned with its lousy tool support and performance impacts too many times. Every release of clang has made ObjC++ a bit better, and it's possible that some day my bias won't be accurate and ObjC++ will be a fine language to work in. But I don't think that day is today, and I think Swift++ will come before that's true anyway.)